# Working off of the results of 2 Conditional Formats

Tags: database, excel

Another ? for you. How can I work off of the results of 2 Conditional Formats & have just the results of those conditions highlighted.  The 2 Conditional Formats results are in (column C & G) & I need to have the results highlighted in (column A)... A's 3 arguments are as follows:

condition1  cell value  equal to 0, No Format

condition2  formula is  =$G27>=LARGE($G$27:$G$150,10), Bold Format

condition3  formula is  =$C27>=LARGE($C$27:$C$150,10), Colored Red

Another quandry...

Answer (score 0):

This is just like the [fizzbuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) programmer test.

So, without writing the code for you: I'll recommend a loop through a 'listobject(table)' followed by setting the range values using '.interior.colorindex' or 'font.colorindex' properties.

OK, without using code...
 - Format your table as a table using "Format as Table" function
 - In the "Table" menu, select the "Total Row" checkbox
 - Set your **Total** formula for Cols C and G as `=LARGE([ColC],10)` and `=LARGE([ColG],10)`, respectively.
 - In Conditional Formatting, set up two rules as follows:
    - `=$B28>=$D$[TotalRowlNumber]`
    - `=$B28>=$C$[TotalRowNumber]`
 - You shouldn't need a condition for =0 since you are not changing any formats.

How does that work?

Here's a sample table:

```
ID   Col A    Col C     Col G  
____________________________  
1    50.66    51.33    97.17  
2    16.09    83.39    97.37  
3   b71.94    69.77   28.06  
4    21.60    20.59    21.14  
5    33.62    65.58    39.21  
6    21.96    34.59    17.99  
7  br80.94    93.02    96.84  
8   b70.53    37.53    29.60  
9    32.06    37.38     0.15  
10 br89.81    67.02     6.85  
11 br89.76    64.65    74.00  
12   47.94    46.06     1.71  
13  b61.19    34.19    90.13  
14 br79.11    35.77    86.97  
15   39.89    79.15    77.88  
16 br93.20     8.01    13.99  
17   31.84    18.12    95.61  
18 br99.78    19.99     3.89  
19   38.94    32.12    18.56  
20   13.17    22.23    61.82  
21 br75.75    51.42    28.32  
22  b55.89    49.93    76.30  
23 br72.78    82.46    27.07  
24  b57.20    31.26    76.90  
25    6.46     6.85     2.78  
Total         51.33    74.00
```

Use the `LARGE()` formula to get the 10th largest value in the TOTAL row.
Then reference this cell in the condition.
So, any number larger than 51.33 will be bold and any number larger than 74.00 will be bold red.  (Note, I used random number generator, so the numbers may be good or bad.)
Also, I added a 'b' tag and an 'r' note where cells will be formatted bold and red, respectively.

Comment: Can you see a way without "writing code" and sticking with conditional format to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are your current conditions not working?  Have you tried setting up 3 individual conditions?  Overlapping ranges for condition are generally acceptable.

Comment: I believe setting up 3 conditions is the way to go. But I have to find proper argument for Cond1 to prevent having to weekly change the parameters of the argument.  For example:  when Cond 2 & 3 are set up as Cond 1 & 2; I have to change the ‘10’ after the “LARGE” argument, to the exact number dependant on the specific week.  For instance in another example that works like a charm I have used:

condition1     cell value equal to 0      No Format
condition2     formula is        =$G27>=LARGE($G$27:$G$150,10), Bold Format. 

I’m on that elusive search…

Comment: Can you show an example of your data or table?  Also, why do you need to change the parameter on a weekly basis?  Can you make that a formula also?

Comment: Thank you Sammy... I'll try it & let you know how it goes.... A large snag is I'm currently restricted by using Excel 2003 for the present time being....   Do you foresee any problems with using 2003?

Comment: I'm using 2007 and so it shouldn't be too different; the Large() formula is pretty basic and even if the Total Row function doesn't exist in '03, you can still manually create one.  (PS - mark my answer if it works...I need the rep!)

Comment: I'm new to stack    One question how can I show you an example of what I'm working on?

Comment: I’m searching for a format for ColumnA that basically does the same thing ColC & ColG so I won’t have to change the parameter weekly.  ColumnA is working off of ColC & ColG (each with 2 conditions themselves)  

Cond1   =$G7>=LARGE($G$7:$G$43,1)   Font=Black, Bold    
    
ColG is set with 2 Conditions  
Cond1  CellValueIs  EqualTo  0
Cond2  FormulaIs  =$G7>=LARGE($G$7:$G$43,37)

(Cont)

Comment: By setting "No Format" as the first Cond; and the LARGE Cond as the second, the resultant is only the numbers are highlighted excluding the 0’s.  

Cond2   =$C7>=LARGE($C$7:$C$43,10)  Font=Red, Normal

ColC is set with the identical format as Cond1, but is set C’s as the variable. 
 
Presently I have to change Cond1 to suit how many results I have for the data on a weekly basis.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - tell me if I've got this right: first, if "0" ColA gets no format; if value in ColA is larger than the 10th largest value in ColC format as **bold**; if value in ColA is larger than the 10th largest value in ColG format as red.  Is that right?  If so, then what I showed you should work.

Comment: To show data, you'll just have to build a little table using the markdown that SO provides.

Comment: Col(umn)A has 3 Cond(itions). The problem is Cond2’s nth largest number - LARGE(from this list, nth largest number). I want to replace the nth largest number with a variable statement so it will change automatically depending on the weekly results. Presently, (see below) I have to change Col(umn)A, Cond2, nth largest number to suit how many results I have for the data on a weekly basis. Cond1 CellValueIs EqualTo 0 Cond2 FormulaIs =$G7>=LARGE($G$7:$G$43,37) Font=Black, Bold Cond3 FormulaIs =$C7>=LARGE($C$7:$C$43,10) Font=Red, Normal

Comment: Then you should set up a cell (usually at the bottom of the table) that holds the `LARGE()` formula; then refer to that cell in the Condition statement.

Comment: Thank you Sammy...   And all of these formulae & formats can be used in Excel 2003?

Comment: As I said above, I'm using 2007, so there may be some differences, but the formulas should not have changed.